# pm-utils broke my system and didn't fix it when I purged it and all of its dependencies

Tags: 12.04, pm-utils

Before I installed pm-utils, closing the lid just turned the screen off. I installed pm-utils, and now the screen turns off and my system crashes, kind of a big issue. I then purged pm-utils and all its dependencies, but my system still crashes when I close the lid(lovely).

Tested with a live CD, the screen just turns off when the lid is closed, which makes sense.
This is an Ubuntu 12.04 minimal install, what do I have to edit to get this back to normal?

Edit: if I close the lid, wait for two popping noises, open the lid, and then switch to a VT, it returns to the original non-crashing behavior. I am pretty sure this makes no sense.

Edit: wait nope, it seems to work, except....all disk I/O gets stuck.

Edit: purging Dbus fixed it, although I did lose half of my applications in the process.

Comment: I think that pm-utils is installed by default on Ubuntu. I believe it makes the default action to suspend when you close the lid. Can you suspend the system when you aren't closing the lid?

Comment: It is not installed by default on a minimal install, no, I cannot suspend, I've played with the various quirk modes but it just crashes. I really don't care, this laptop is a "desktop replacement" and wouldn't last for an hour on battery suspending anyway. I just want the original behavior back without re-installing.

Comment: Can you edit the default lid closing behavior in settings?

Comment: I do not have said settings, this is a minimal install, rather I don't know where they are because it's probably some strange and arcane file /etc/ that pm-utils decided was a good idea to edit(and not normalize when it was uninstalled). Either way, no graphical settings to play with

Comment: Not an answer just have a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

I found two configuration options in gnome that should change the default lid close action.

`org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action` and `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action`.

To set your computer to not suspend on close, I believe that you could set both of these settings to `black`.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action blank
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action blank
```

I am not entirely sure that these will work on your system, though they do on mine.

Source: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.5/power-closelid.html.en

Comment: Don't have gnome, don't have a DE, don't have much else that you wouldn't find on a minimal install, basically I've got dhcpd a system logger and a single X driver on here; but for obvious reasons testing for this issue is being done without X.

Comment: Ah, I am not sure then. I don't know what is controlling the default lid close action in a minimal install :/. You might be able to re install pm-utils and change the default lid close operation using it, but I am not sure.